# Spring Web application displaying HTTP Status 404 -

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc

Hi I know this question has been asked and answered many many times..I checked various question on `stackoverflow` and on other web pages but still unable to find the solution

I am  vert much beginner to `Spring MVC`.

I am trying to create a simple `HelloWorld` Program using `Spring MVC- Controller`.

I have written the following code, but its giving me `HTTP Status 404` when i try to access `http://localhost:5151/SpringMaven/`

This is my project hierarchy

[image]

**Web.xml**

```
 <servlet>
    <servlet-name>dispatcher</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>
        org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet
    </servlet-class>
    <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
</servlet>
<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>dispatcher</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
```

**Spring Configuration File**

```
<context:component-scan base-package="com.evantage.controller" />

<bean id="viewResolver"
    class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceViewResolver">
    <property name="viewClass"
        value="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.JstlView" />
    <property name="prefix" value="/WEB-INF/jsp/" />
    <property name="suffix" value=".jsp" />
</bean>
```

**Controller**

```
@Controller
public class HelloController {


    @RequestMapping("/welcome")
    public ModelAndView helloWorld() {

        String message = "Hello World";
        return new ModelAndView("welcome", "message", message);
    }
}
```

I have been trying for 2 days, but unable to get success. Kindly guide me

Thanks

Comment: access this http://localhost:5151/SpringMaven/welcome  what is the output

Comment: same error message, HTTP Status 404 -

Comment: What is the name of the Spring Configuration File?

Comment: dispatcher-servlet.xml

Comment: Did you deploy your web app to Tomcat? AFAIK, it uses port 8080 by default. if you are using Tomcat configured at port 5151, can you verify that Tomcat is up and running by just opening `http://localhost:5151`?

Comment: Yes it running, I am using Pivotal TC Server

Comment: which version of spring you are using and check lib are available or not while running the tomcat

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try with this `web.xml`:

```
<context-param>
    <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
    <param-value>/WEB-INF/dispatcher-servlet.xml</param-value>
</context-param>

<listener>
    <listener-class>org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener</listener-class>
</listener>
<listener>
    <listener-class>org.springframework.web.util.IntrospectorCleanupListener</listener-class>
</listener>

<servlet>
    <servlet-name>dispatcher</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet</servlet-class>

    <init-param>
        <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
        <param-value>com.evantage</param-value>
    </init-param>
    <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
</servlet>

<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>dispatcher</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
```

And enable autowire in your dispatcher:

```
<!-- Enable autowire -->
<context:annotation-config />
```

Comment: Now i am receving following error message
`HTTP Status 500 - Servlet.init() for servlet dispatcher threw exception`

Comment: `: IOException parsing XML document from ServletContext resource [/com.evantage]; nested exception is java.io.FileNotFoundException: Could not open ServletContext resource [/com.evantage]`

Comment: it's obviously looking for the path to your configuration `<param-value>com.evantage</param-value>`. try to put the location of your spring xml context `<param-value>/WEB-INF/dispatcher-servlet.xml</param-value>`

Answer (score 1):

Try to add this to Spring Configuration File:

```
 <mvc:annotation-driven>
```

And add this in schema in top:

```
 http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc
```

Comment: Its giving me following error `The prefix "mvc" for element "mvc:annotation-driven" is not bound.`

Answer (score 0):

Add those line in your dispatcher-servlet.

```
<context:component-scan base-package="com.evantage"/>
<bean class="org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.support.ControllerClassNameHandlerMapping"/>
<bean class="org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.annotation.DefaultAnnotationHandlerMapping" />
<bean class="org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.annotation.AnnotationMethodHandlerAdapter" />
```

Add those line in web.xml

```
<listener>
        <listener-class>org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener</listener-class>
</listener>
```

Let me know what is the output.

**UPDATE:**
In dispatcher-servlet.xml add those line in `<bean>` tag.

```
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
       xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
       xmlns:mvc="http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc"
       xmlns:p="http://www.springframework.org/schema/p"
       xmlns:tx="http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx"
       xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
       xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.0.xsd
       http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx/spring-tx-2.5.xsd
       http://www.springframework.org/schema/context
       http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context.xsd
       http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc
       http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc/spring-mvc-3.0.xsd"
>
```

Comment: Thanks for response.. I am still getting the same 404- page

Comment: If not, then i would like to know your server configuration. which server used and does it maintain the port 5151.

Answer (score -1):

Because you try to access `/SpringMaven` URL, but you've bound your controller action to `/welcome` path.

Either change `@RequestMapping` annotation to use expected URL, or go to `http://localhost:5151/welcome`.

-edit-

And make sure your controller is registred as a service - either register by hand in Spring configuration or enable MVC annotations scanning so Spring can auto-find the `@Controller`-annotated service.